# Issue saving file using AutoIt

Tags: automation, automated-tests, autoit

I have an application, wherein I get a "Save As" dialog-box. At times, if a file exists with the same name, another dialog box with the same name "Save As" is being shown. The following is the code I wrote but it doesn't work as expected.

```cpp
Global $sTitle = "Save As"

WinWait($sTitle)
WinWaitActive($sTitle)

ControlClick($sTitle, "Save", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:&Save; INSTANCE:2]")
ControlSetText($sTitle, "", "CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]", $file_name)

SendKeepActive($sTitle)
Send("{ENTER}")
Sleep(4000)
WinWaitActive($sTitle,"",3)

If WinExists($sTitle, "No") Then Send("{ENTER}")
If WinExists("Exit OmniPeek") Then
    Send("{ENTER}")
Else
    Sleep(2000)
    WinClose($closing_file)
EndIf
```

The idea is to check if the 2nd "Save As" dialog box is displayed and if it does, over-write the existing file. This however, doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone help me with this script? You can re-create the issue by using Notepad as well. Just have a file with a name abc.txt and try to save a file with the same name. You will get another dialog box with the name "Save As".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Example()

Func Example()
    ; Run Notepad
    Run("notepad.exe")

    ; Wait 10 seconds for the Notepad window to appear.
    Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10)

    ; Keep the Notepad window active when using the Send function.
    SendKeepActive("[CLASS:Notepad]")

    ; Simulate entering a string of text. If you try to change to a different window other than Notepad, then the Notepad window will
    ; be brought to focus again.
    For $i = 1 To 10
        Sleep(5)
        Send("notepad - ")
    Next

    ; Disable the Notepad window being active when using the Send function.
    SendKeepActive("")

    ; Close the Notepad window using the handle returned by WinWait.
    WinClose($hWnd)

    Send("{ENTER}") ; <<< SAVE

    ; Now a screen will pop up and ask to save the changes, the classname of the window is called
    ; "#32770" and simulating the "TAB" key to move to the second button in which the "ENTER" is simulated to not "save the file"
    WinWaitActive("[CLASS:#32770]", '', 2)
    Sleep(50)
    Send('newName.txt')
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{TAB}{ENTER}")
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```